# Как в WordPress создать расширенную форму регистрации пользователей? без плагина!

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Как в WordPress создать расширенную форму регистрации пользователей, нужно добавить номер телефона и пол, в каком файле это сделать?, верстку допилил в файле 
wp-login.php? но что делать дальше, как добавить поля в таблицу и т.д, как их туда сохранить? и чтобы эти поля отображадись паралельно в админке wp. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Плагинофобам читать обязательно: https://wpmag.ru/2014/functions-php/ !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Исправлять файлы ядра нельзя!

Регистрация делается очень просто:

Создаем форму

```
<div class="registration">
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'registration', 'registration_nonce' ) ?>
        <input type="text" name="username" required="required"/>
        <input type="password" name="password" required="required"/>
        <input type="email" name="email" required="required"/>
        <input type="tel" name="phone" required="required"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Регистрация">
    </form>
</div>
```

Обрабатываем ее

```
add_action( 'wp', 'registration' );
function registration() {
    $nonce = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'registration_nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'registration' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $username = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $password = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $email    = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL );
    $phone    = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'phone', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    // Validate fields...
    $user = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user, 'phone', $phone ); // Сохраняем доп. поля
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user, true ); // Авторизируем пользователя
        $uri = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        wp_safe_redirect( $uri, 302 ); // Редирект после входа на страницу
    }
}
```

Вывести на списке всех пользователя доп. информацию:

```
add_filter( 'manage_candidate_posts_columns', 'register_column' );
add_action( 'manage_candidate_posts_custom_column', 'column_callback' );
function register_column( array $columns ): array {
    return array_slice( $columns, 0, 4 ) + [ 'phone' => 'Phone' ] + array_slice( $columns, 4 );
}

function column_callback( string $output, string $column_name, int $user_id ): string {
    if ( 'phone' === $column_name ) {
        $phone  = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', true );
        $output = '<a href="tel:' . $phone . '">' . $phone . '</a>';
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!) на момент вашего ответа, уже решил задачу, и сделал регистрацию через ajax, но еще раз большое спасибо